# Tensor square of a torsion-free module ($R$ domain)

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Linked to my comment [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367214/the-natural-map-m-to-m-otimes-r-k-is-injective-iff-m-is-torsion-free).

> Let $M$ be a torsion-free module over a domain $R$. Is $M\otimes_R M$ torsion-free ? If not, a counterexample would be appreciated.

Comment: For a counter example, try $(x,y)=M\subset R=k[x,y]$.

Comment: By $(x,y)$ do you mean $(x)+(y)$ ?

Comment: @Duchamp $(x,y) = (x) + (y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I believe is the argument Mohan had in mind:

Let $k$ be a field and $x$ and $y$ indeterminates. Set 
$$
R:=k[x,y],\quad M:=(x,y)\subset R.
$$ 
As we have 
$$
xy\ (x\otimes y-y\otimes x)=x^2\otimes y^2-x^2\otimes y^2=0
$$ 
in $M\otimes_RM$, it suffices to check $x\otimes y\ne y\otimes x$ (again in $M\otimes_RM$).

To do that we equip $k$ with an $R$-module structure by letting $x$ and $y$ act by zero, and we note that the map $M\otimes_RM\to k$, 
$$
(f\otimes g)\mapsto\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(0,0)
$$ 
is well-defined, $R$-linear and sends $x\otimes y$ to $1$ and $y\otimes x$ to $0$.

Comment: OK, very nice method !

Answer (score 3):

Following the suggestions of Mohan and Ben, I put here an example of torsionfree (and even torsionless) module $M$ over a domain $R$ such that its tensor square $M\otimes_R M$ has torsion. If, of course, somebody has a shorter proof/construction, I'll be delighted to accept his/her answer.

Let $k$ be a field and $x,y$ two commuting variables; set $R=k[x,y]$. As a $k$-algebra, $R$ is graded by the total degree 
$$
R_n=span_k\{x^py^q|p+q=n\}
$$ 
Consider the ideal $M:=R_{\geq 1}=\oplus_{n\geq 1}R_n=(x)+(y)=(x,y)$. As a $k$ vector space $M$ is graded by the preceding definition (the range of degrees is $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$). We first look at the tensor square 
$M\otimes_k M$ and its graded structure given by 
$$
(M\otimes_k M)_n=\oplus_{p+q=n}R_p\otimes_k R_q\ .
$$
(this time, the range of degrees is $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$) and we consider the quotient 
$$
N={(M\otimes_k M)}/{(M\otimes_k M)_{\geq 3}}
$$
and, denoting by $s:(M\otimes_k M)\to N$ the canonical quotient mapping, we see that $N$ has $k$-dimension 4 with basis $B=\{e_{ab}\}_{a,b\in \{x,y\}}$ with $e_{ab}=s(a\otimes_k b)$. Now, one checks easily that the $k$-bilinear map
\begin{align*}
M \times M &\to N, \\
(u,v) &\mapsto \Phi_k(u\otimes_k v)=s(u\otimes_k v)
\end{align*}
is, in fact, $R$-bilinear (check it with monomials $x^py^q$). Hence it gives rise to a linear map $\Phi_R : M \otimes_R M \to N$. This suffices to prove that 
$t=x\otimes_R y-y\otimes_R x\not=0$ as $\Phi_R(t)=e_{xy}-e_{yx}$ (note that $t\in M\otimes_R M$). But now 
$$
x.t=x^2\otimes_R y-xy\otimes_R x=x\otimes_R xy-x\otimes_R yx=0
$$
which shows the claim.

**Late edit** Here, tensor products are thought and constructed as in 
Bourbaki Algebra II § 3 eq. (1). More precisely, if $M$ (resp. $N$) 
is a $B$-module on the right (resp. $N$ is a $B$-module on the left), 
$M\otimes_B N$ is a the solution of the universal problem with 
$f, (M\times N)\to G$ bi-additive and satisfying, 
for $x\in M,\ y\in N,\ \lambda\in B$ 
$$
f(x\lambda,y)=f(x,\lambda y)
$$ 
but, if $M,N$ have other structures commuting with the $B$-actions, the 
tensor product $M\otimes_B N$ automatically inherits these properties. For example, here, as $R$ is commutative, all $R$-modules are $R-R$-bimodules.

Comment: Torsionless and torsion-free are different notions.

Comment: Of course, I added [(and even torsionless)] in the text and accepted Darij's edits. I think/hope it sounds better now.

Comment: $xy\ (x\otimes y-y\otimes x)=x^2\otimes y^2-x^2\otimes y^2=0$

Comment: True if $\otimes=\otimes_R$ and I think not if $\otimes=\otimes_k$

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. - In the question you wrote $\otimes_R$, right? (Please use the `@`sign if you want me to be notified of your comment.)

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Point taken. I think in your comment, you mean $\otimes=\otimes_R$ this was ambiguous because your comment was after my answer (not my question) where I use two kinds of $\otimes$.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. - You're right, I should have been clearer. I believe my comment answers the question and is what Mohan had in mind. What am I missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88848/discussion-between-duchamp-gerard-h-e-and-pierre-yves-gaillard).